# Decimal value is read as scientific notation in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-services

I have a Windows service which reads a .csv from a particular folder and puts it in sql server. I have the code shown below:

private void updateWorkOrder(List etchRecord)

```
    {
        object[] objArr = new object[] { Convert.ToInt32(etchRecord[1]), 
                    Convert.ToDateTime(etchRecord[2]), 
                    Convert.ToDateTime(etchRecord[3]),
                    Convert.ToDecimal(etchRecord[4]), 
                    Convert.ToInt32(etchRecord[5]),
                    **Convert.ToDecimal(etchRecord[6])};** --> this field
        dbManager.ExecDataSet("usp_EtchRate_SaveWorkOrderData", objArr); 
    }
```

And I have a stored procedure in sql server which is responsible for stroing it in sql table. The problem is it shows the decimal values in the field which i shown above as scientific notation. I even tried changing to text but it doesn't work

Comment: Is the value stored in the MS SQL table as a scientific notation?  Or is it stored properly and being read (by the above code) in scientific notation?

Comment: @Dbloch The value is stored as scientific notation in sql server. The .csv file has the value in scientific notation and even the Windows service reads it as decimal (i tested it using debugger). But somehow, between the win service and sql stored procedure, the value is changed to scientific notation.